# Retrieve call forwarding (routing) rules of a Lync client

Tags: c#, lync, ucma, lync-server-2013

How can I retrieve the call forwarding (routing) rules of a lyn client using UCMA or MSPL? 
I have tried to retrieve it using a UserEndpoint and subscribing to the `PresenceNotificationReceived` event of `RemotePresenceView`.
Unfortunately this seems not to work. According to the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454661.aspx) it is only possible to query the route category with a local-access (`LocalOwnerPresence`).

Another options would be to use an ApplicationEndpoint of impersonate every user for which I want the retrieve the call forwarding rules. But in my eyes this seems to be a dirty solution.

Could this be also be done with MSPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my tests this:

> Another options would be to use an ApplicationEndpoint of impersonate every user for which I want the retrieve the call forwarding rules. But in my eyes this seems to be a dirty solution.

Has been the only working solution (outside of querying the database directly).

If you want this done in MSPL, look at [QueryCategory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439174.aspx). The problem there is you will need the correct `ContainerNumber` and `Instance` ids.

However, if you look them up (See [MSDN for Presence data source and category instance ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454680.aspx)) you will find there is no instance numbers listed for routing. The container number info can be found here: [Routing category instance value element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454776.aspx), and that one does list some instance IDs.

Interesting point is that routing data is classified as "local only", see [Local-access only category instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454661.aspx):

> The routing category instances contain routing rules to forward inbound calls made by any members of a hosting container. They are private category instances and are not visible to the remote users who are members of the hosting containers.

So far I have not found a combination of name (`'routing'`), `ContainerNumber` and `Instance` id that give any results, so please update if you find anything.

Comment: Yes, probably you have the `AutomaticPresencePublicationEnabled` property set to `true` in the user endpoint settings. This automatically publishes the user as online when you connect the endpoint. Set it to false and subscribe to presence manually: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.rtc.collaboration.userendpointsettings.automaticpresencepublicationenabled_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncuc3cr%28v=office.15%29 Also set the endpoint's state to offline before connecting: `userEndpointSettings.Presence.UserPresenceState = PresenceState.UserOffline`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the `AutomaticPresencePublicationEnabled` property was set to `true`.
What do you mean with "subscribe to presence manually"?
Because when I subscribe to `myUserEndpoint.LocalOwnerPresence.PresenceNotificationReceived`, I only get the routing information, when they are changed but I have to receive them immediately.

Comment: Might be better to put this in a new question instead of comments, but here goes. You need to add an eventhandler to the presence received event before establishing. Create an endpoint with `AutomaticPresencePublicationEnabled = false` and `UserPresenceState = PresenceState.UserOffline`. Handle the `LocalPresenceNotificationReceived` event, after that call `Establish`, and when established call `LocalOwnerPresence.Subscribe`. Soon your handler should fire with all 'current' settings.